# is it possible to proove somebody that had access to your e-mail password has deleted my personal e-mail, pics etc from their computer not mine

Tags: email

going through messy probate, foolishy gave my deceased boyfriends daughter my email address and password.  she said she needed it for family business purposes but has since deleted my personal pic's somehow a ton of stuff is encrypted dont know it that is related but she definately deleted personal e-mails and pics of mine.  my lawyer wants me to see if i can proove she did that.  is that possible to see if that was done not from my computer at home but from hers.

Answer (score 0):

Email services like Gmail and Hotmail store the last sessions and the IP Addresses from which the account was accessed.

If you have a Gmail account, do the following:

1. Open the inbox and scroll to the bottom.
2. On the bottom right side you will find the text similar to:

> Last account activity: 2 Minutes ago Details

1. Click on the **Details link** to open a new window that will show all the recent account access along with the IP Addresses.

While this is not enough to "prove" that she did delete the emails - it will still give you enough data to show that your account was indeed accessed by someone other than you at a certain time period (different ip, different city etc.)

You will be able to see a different IP address used to access your account in the list. The next step could be finding the location of that IP Address using a free service called IP Tracker Online:

[IP Tracker Online](http://www.iptrackeronline.com/)

Enter the IP address that you find is different from the usual ones and find it's location.

If you are lucky and get the right location, you will be in a better position to justify that somebody else (with an X IP Address and located at Y Place) accessed your account at a certain time and possibly prove it sufficiently.

Comment: thank you so much, ive had nothing but trouble with my computer since shes had access, even though i dont use that e-mail any more.  i have norton security and they say they dont see that ive been compromised but an entire host of problems ive had makes me feel like she still has some control somehow, its driving me crazy.  thanks again it will give me some peace of mind if i can show an ip address that is not mineq

Comment: Adding to this post - any decent email server will have some kind of session logging - its a matter of approaching your service provider ASAP - and - if neccessary - with the written support of your lawyer - to ask them for the relevant logs (or, if they don't want to give these to you, that they preserve them while you get a court order...)